# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial - Where can I find source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I see in the front of my book that the source code is "Released under the MIT license" but don't seem to be able to find it anywhere. Does anyone know if it's available? I probably just missed it somewhere in the book "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example" Copyright 2011 by Michael Hartl.
thanks!
Bill

Comment: please add the title, author and edition of the book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about railstutorial. If so, the code is available at github
https://github.com/railstutorial